# Django dynamic field output as CSV

Tags: django, csv

Hi I am writing a Django view which generates a csv file. Pretty straightforward. In my view I have:

```
def mysearch(request, exportCSV):
    ...
    if 'q' in request.GET or exportCSV:
        results_list = request.session['results_list']
    ...
    if exportCSV:
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(response)

        # write field titles                
        writer.writerow(['name_of_firstfield', 'name_of_secondfield', ... ,])

        for row in results_list: 
            # write row content
            writer.writerow([row.firstfield, row.secondfield, ... , ])
        return response
```

There are actually two questions here:

1. How do I output the name of a model field as text so I can write the field titles to the first row.
2. How can I avoid specifying each field (considering I have a lot of fields) for both lines. I basically want to say for each row, output each field name then output each piece of data.

Can I somehow use `getattr` here?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/790/) as a example, you can access a models field names via `model._meta.fields` and  you can use `getattr()` to get the value of a field for a given object. e.g.

```
fields = ct_object._meta.fields

writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow([field.column for field in fields])

for object in objects_to_export:
    writer.writerow([getattr(object, field.name) for field in fields])
```

Comment: +1, except better to use `field.name` rather than column as the header.

Comment: Good answer. However, my query is quite complex and involves multiple joins, so I think I'm stuck with listing the required fields at some point in the process.